# How do we convert time in unix timestamp to string with radix 32 in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I want to convert the current time in unix timestamp to a string with radix 32 in MySQL

It can be achieved in JavaScript with the code below

```
'm' + prefix + Date.now().toString(32) + suffix
```

Sample SQL to give the idea (working incorrectly )

```
SET prefix = 'order'
SET suffix = 19;
SELECT 'm' + prefix + CONV( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), 10, 32 ) + suffix AS   result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is considered an arithmetic operator in `MySQL`.

You need to use `CONCAT` function to concatenate multiple strings like below:

```
SELECT CONCAT('m' , prefix , CONV( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 10, 32 ) , suffix) AS   result
```

**Note:** `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) would return same value.`

**TEST:**

```
SET @prefix := 'PRE';
SET @suffix := 'SUF';

SELECT CONCAT('m' , @prefix , CONV( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 10, 32 ) , @suffix) AS   result
```

**Output:**  `mPRE1BSVENHSUF`

<kbd>[**See Live Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/77894/2)</kbd>